# Need help to write xpath to fetch the value

Tags: xpath

I have an XMl where in there are multiple rows, I have to fetch a value from a row cell depending on a value in a different cell in the same row

```
<row bandingIndex="" isDirty="false" odfPk="5001001" >
   <cell id="selector" type="checkbox">
      <data value="5001001"/>
   </cell>
   <cell isDirty="false" isTsv="" nowrap="true" type="label">
      <label value="1234project_1234"/>
      <data id="id" value="5001001"/>
      <data id="returnAction" value="projmgr.organizerTaskListReturn"/>
      <data id="projectId" value="5001001"/>
      </action>
   </cell>
   <cell isDirty="false" isTsv="" nowrap="true" type="label">
      <tip value="1234project"/>
      <action actionId="projmgr.orgTask2ProjectLink" id="projmgr.orgTask2ProjectLink" type="url">
         <label value="1234project"/>
         <data id="taskId" value="5001001"/>
         <data id="id" value="5001001"/>
      </action>
   </cell>
</row>
```

In the above example, I have to fetch the value from first cell/data/value having the `id = 'selector'` depending on the `cell/tip[@value='1234project']` without hardcoding the index of the cell.

`/row/cell/data/@value` returns always the first row value, but I would have multiple rows.

Comment: Next time use a tool to format your HTML markup : http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first narrow your selection to the correct `row`...

```
/row[cell/tip/@value='1234project']
```

Then select the correct `cell`...

```
cell[@id='selector']
```

Then select the `data/@value`.

Complete XPath:

```
/row[cell/tip/@value='1234project']/cell[@id='selector']/data/@value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select `cell` having `tip[@value='1234project']` then use `preceding-sibling::cell` to go to corresponding `<cell id="selector">`. From this point you can easily get corresponding `data/@value`. Full XPath :

```
/row/cell[tip[@value = '1234project']]/preceding-sibling::cell[@id='selector']/data/@value
```